# Probability Density Function Example Help

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

I am reading through the text, "Introduction to Probability Theory with Contemporary Applications" by Lester Helms. I am stuck on the attached example. I understand how the author obtained the joint density function, but I am struggling to understand how he got f_x(x) and f_y(y). This is my first post on this website so please excuse any errors.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

[Example 3.14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvU6G.png)

Comment: You have $f_X(x) = \sum_{y=1}^\infty f(x,y)$; i.e., "the marginal of $X$ is obtained by summing/integrating the joint probability function over all values of $Y$."

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I am still confused about this problem. Why do we sum over all values of Y if we are interested in the probability density function of x? Also when we look for $f_y(y)$, why does the author sum from x=y to n?

Comment: For the second comment: he actually sums $f(x,y)$ for $x=1$ to $\infty$, but $f(x,y)=$ for most of these values -- only the ones you mention remain. cf. the formula for $f(x,y)$.

Comment: For the first comment: we are looking for the probability that $X$ is equal to $x$, for some fixed value $x$. Now, hen does that happen? Either we have $X=x$ and $Y=1$, or $X=x$ and $Y=2$, or $X=x$ and $Y=3$, etc. All these mutually exclusive events are the cases where $X=x$; and we know the probabilities $f(x,1)$, $f(x,2)$, etc. of each of them. So the probability we want ($f_X(x)$) is the sum of these probabilities: $\sum_{y} f_X(x,y)$.

Comment: Thank you so much. That makes more sense.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the joint probability *mass* function: $$\begin{align}f_{X,Y}(x,y) =&~\begin{cases}2/(n(n+1)) & : 1\leq y\leq x\leq n ,\, (x,y)\in\Bbb Z^2 \\ 0 & : \textsf{otherwise}\end{cases}
\\[1ex] =&~ \frac 2{n(n+1)} \mathbf 1_{x\in\{1..n\}, y\in \{1.. x\}}\end{align}$$

The marginal probability mass function of $X$ is the sum over the possible values of $Y$, for a specified value of $X$ in $\{1..n\}$.   When $X$ realises the integer value $x$ then $Y$ can be any integer value from $1$ to $x$.   Thus:$$\begin{align}f_X(x) =&~ \sum_{\psi=1}^x f_{X,Y}(x,\psi)\mathbf 1_{x\in\{1..n\}}\\[1ex] =&~ \sum_{\psi=1}^x \frac 2{n(n+1)}\mathbf 1_{x\in\{1..n\}} \\[1ex] =&~ \frac {2x}{n(n+1)}\mathbf 1_{x\in\{1..n\}} \end{align}$$

The marginal probability mass function of $Y$ is the sum of the joint probability over the possible values of $X$, for a specified value of $Y$ in $\{1..n\}$.   When $Y$ realises the integer value $y$ then $X$ can be any integer value from $y$ to $n$.   Thus:$$\begin{align}f_Y(y) =&~ \sum_{\chi=y}^n f_{X,Y}(\chi,y)\mathbf 1_{y\in\{1..n\}}\\[1ex] =&~ \sum_{\chi=y}^n \frac 2{n(n+1)}\mathbf 1_{y\in\{1..n\}} \\[1ex] =&~ \frac {2(n-y+1)}{n(n+1)}\mathbf 1_{y\in\{1..n\}} \end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you! Your explanations helped. I am not sure why and how you changed $\frac{2}{n(n+1)}$ to $\frac{2}{n(n-1)}$ and how this helps.

Comment: Miss read the blurry image.